# RStudio not reading data frame and getting the connection stuck?

Tags: r

I'm starting with R and I'm trying to load a data frame that I have on my PC.
It's a txt, tab delimited file. I already tested the file by copying and pasting it in Excel, so I know it's properly formatted.

However, when using

```
myData <- read.table("mydata.txt", header = TRUE, sep = "\t")
myData
```

All I get is an error message saying

```
Error: object 'myData' not found
```

But mydata.txt is located in the same folder where the R file is located at.
Also, notice it's not saying "file not found", if I change the file name to some gibberish like "dsfkad.txt", it will throw an error saying no such file with that name was found.
Furthermore, it seems that the connection with the file gets stuck after you run the command once. If I try to run the command again, all I get in the console is

`>`

No error output or anything, just the angled bracket.
If I do a change in the code and run it again, it then shows the error

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open connection
```

So it seems like RStudio is not actually closing the file connection after trying to read it and its throwing errors when anything changes, which seems like very abnormal behavior for an IDE.

Comment: Check your working directory with getwd() Just because the .R file and the .txt file are in the same directory doesn't mean that your working directory is there.

Comment: Your error says `mydata` but the code says `myData`. If that's not the issue you should edit the question so it doesn't look like it is.